# How to stream video using AirPlay from VLCKit player

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, apple-tv, vlckit

I have implemented player using VLCKit to play the live streaming video and now I want to play it on Apple TV through AirPlay. But everything that I found on Internet was about using AVPlayer for streaming to Apple TV. But AVPlayer doesn’t suit for my goals.

I’ll appreciate any help)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, VLCKit does not support Airplay 2 at this point.